# Trying to create a function that repeats a function

Tags: python

I have a helping function:

```
def incr(x):
    return x+1
```

I want to create a function named "repeated" that use "incr" function n times on a certain parameter

In the end I want to use the "repeated" function in this **matter only** :

```
repeated (incr, 4)(2)
```

That for example will output 6.

So far I tried to do this:

```
def repeated(f, n):
    func, x = f
    for i in range(n):
        func(x)
```

But it gave me an error saying I can't unpack a non Tuple function.
It doesn't seem like I don't have access in the function to the "(2)"

Comment: Repeated must return a function that takes the (2).

Comment: FWIW, your repeated function still would not work since it just throws away the result. You might want to write down what should be called with what input - the code will be a rather straightforward translation of that.

Comment: True my function didn't returned any results.
Now I understand it has to return a function for it to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the `repeated`function must return a function

```
def repeated(func, n):
    def repeatedfunc(x):
        rsl = x
        for i in range(n):
            rsl = func(rsl)
        return rsl
    return repeatedfunc

def incr(x):
    return x+1

rslt = repeated(incr, 4)(2)
print(rslt)
```

output

```
6
```

Comment: Please note that this implementation (needlessly...) has some bugs: It prevents re-using the ``repeated`` function, "exhausting" ``n`` for all future calls. That's doubly problematic since it does not work for ``n=0`` – it will erroneously make at least one call, then get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!
It works perfetcly after a one tweak
I changed the while loop into this for i in range(1, n)
And it worked perfecty!

Comment: @MisterMiyagi perfectly true but meet the spec "I want to use the "repeated" function in this matter only". I have nevertheless edited the code to avoid to get stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: @hpchavaz That is perfectly true and perfectly irrelevant for the quality of the code. Note that the revised code still (needlessly...) miscalculates the ``n=0`` case.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend to use such a syntax construct, for such a task:

```
repeated(incr, 4)(2)
```

Your repeated function must return another function, that will be called by `(2)`.

This should work in your requested manner:

```
def incr(x):
  return x+1

def repeated(f, x):
  # function foo will be returned by repeated and called by (2)
  def foo(n):
    res = x
    for i in range(n):
      res = f(res)
    return res
  return foo

print(repeated(incr, 4)(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

- I think you may want to do something like `functional programming`.
- Add `args` to deal with for different kind of function you want to repeat.
- I can't confirm if there is a position argument what kind of results you want, so I didn't deal with it.

#### code:

```
import functools

def incr(x):
    return x + 1

def incx(x,y = 0):
    return x + y + 1

def repeated_inner(func,args,times):
    head, *rest = args
    for _ in range(times):
        head = func(head, *rest)
    return args[0]

def repeated(func, *args ):
    return functools.partial(repeated_inner, func, args)

print(repeated(incr, 4)(2))
print(repeated(incx, 4)(2))
print(repeated(incx, 4 ,3)(2))
```

#### result

```
6
6
12
```

Comment: Take note that there is no need for the tuple-to-list-to-tuple back and forth conversion. Both tuples and lists can be unpacked via ``*``. If you feel it is necessary to separate the first from the remaining args, you can do so *once* as ``head, *rest = args`` then call ``head = func(head, *rest)`` in the loop.

Answer (score -1):

You should write something like this:

```
def repeated(f, arg_0, n):
    arg = arg_0
    for i in range(n):
        arg = f(arg)
    return arg
```

In a more general situation:

```
def repeated(f, arg):
    def n_f(n):
        result = 0
        for i in range(n):
            result =f(arg)
        return result
   return n_f
```

Comment: Your are not saving the result of `f(arg)` between your loops. Check your result, it's only incrementing +1 to the base value.

Comment: Only when I edited it a bit it did worked.
I needed to declare result = 0 outside of the for loop
And increasing it with f(arg).

Comment: For the first or the second one ? Habebit
I'll edit it for the second one